# How to measure network traffic by protocol?

Tags: windows, networking, wireshark, traffic

I would like to select a type of traffic, as I do in Wireshark, and measure the total traffic in each way for this filter.

Is it possible with Wireshark?

Is it possible with another Windows tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you found your answer but I just wanted to mention for anyone else reading this question, [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/products/ntop/) is an excellent tool for this. [Apparently it can be installed under windows](http://www.ehow.com/how_4468882_install-ntop-windows.html).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A cetain protocol usually means a certain port (or a couple of them).

You can have firewall rules for specific ports and use a firewall that can count the amount of traffic for those rules.

For example, [wipfw](http://wipfw.sourceforge.net/) does that fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just found in Wireshark a menu called Statistics, where you can see the total size of both the captured data and the filtered data.